# What is the [Parameter] Attribute in c#

Tags: c#, blazor

I was watching a tutorial in Blazor. Then I came across this code and I can't seem to find it in the Internet or I think I'm not using the right terms for searching atleast.

```
@code{
[Parameter]
    public IList<Todo> Todo {get; set;}
}
```

Is it only exclusive in blazor or it is available in c#.
Kindly give some references. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's explained in the documentation and the tutorials. `[Parameter]` marks a component's parameters allowing them to be set when the component is added to a page

Comment: kindly give some links because I'm having trouble looking for one that would explain it well.

Comment: [Create and use ASP.NET Core Razor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0), specifically [Component Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#component-parameters)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I've copied that second link into my answer :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is explained in [Create and use ASP.NET Core Razor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0), specifically in the  [Component Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#component-parameters) section.

`[Parameter]` is used to mark the component parameters that can be set when the component is used in another page. Borrowing from the doc example this component doesn't have any parameters :

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">@Title</div>
    <div class="panel-body">@ChildContent</div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnClick">
        Trigger a Parent component method
    </button>
</div>

@code {
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    public EventCallback<MouseEventArgs> OnClick { get; set; }
}
```

Without the `[Parameter]` attribute, those are just public properties that can't be set from other pages. The following line would be invalid :

```
<ChildComponent Title="Panel Title from Parent" />
```

While this :

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">@Title</div>
    <div class="panel-body">@ChildContent</div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnClick">
        Trigger a Parent component method
    </button>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<MouseEventArgs> OnClick { get; set; }
}
```

Allows us to set the parameters whenever we use that component :

```
<ChildComponent Title="Panel Title from Parent"
                OnClick="@ShowMessage">
    Content of the child component is supplied
    by the parent component.
</ChildComponent>
```

Answer (score 5):

All attributes in C# have to reference a type defining that attribute *somewhere*. That Blazor code is still C#.

In this case, I believe it it refers to [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.parameterattribute.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-3.0) - the documentation is currently MIA, but that may well improve over time. There's more detail in the [Blazor documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#component-parameters).

In general, if you have the code in front of you (generally a good idea when watching a tutorial, if at all possible) you can hover over the attribute in Visual Studio to see its fully qualified name or navigate to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using vs code for blazor and Dotnet CLI.

Comment: @ErrolPaleracio: I would *expect* VS Code to still allow you to navigate to the declaration of an attribute.